# How to copy Selected row from DataGridView to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable, ado.net

I have a DataGridView and a DataTable and i want to perform 2 step operation.1st is to copy selected row from DataGridView to DataTable for further processing,2nd step is to remove that row from DataGridView.

Note:I want to Delete Multiple rows one by one so each time i copy a row into DataTable it goes into next Datable Row index.

Here is code i am using to delete selected row from DataTable i want to know what is code for copying this selected row to DataTable.

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            try
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row
```

Using the above line of code you can read you data table row for each selected items.

to Copy

```
var datarow = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row;
newTable.Rows.Add(datarow.ItemArray);
```

full sample code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataTable table = new DataTable();
    private DataTable newTable;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("id",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Desc",typeof(string))
        });
        newTable = table.Copy();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = newTable;
        table.Rows.Add(1, "One");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Two");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Three");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Four");
        table.Rows.Add(5, "Five");
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            try
            {
                var datarow = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row;
                newTable.Rows.Add(datarow.ItemArray);
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @i1yas this answer is helpful mark it as accepted answer. Or, you have found some other answer update the answer and market it.